# How to link header for gcc

Tags: gcc

Sorry for a stupid question, but i really don't know what I do wrong.
I download this repo: https://gitorious.org/gupnp/gupnp/source/ee436107df2ec2aa7ca619b47e2313557bb40d4e
It contain simple example in ./example/ directory and some headers in ./libgupnp/ directory.
One exapmle include `gupnp.h` with this line:

```
#include <libgupnp/gupnp.h>
```

`gupnp.h` located in headers (./libgupnp/) directory.

I start compile it manually with gcc and get

> light-server.c:12:28: fatal error: libgupnp/gupnp.h: No such file or
>   directory

ok, I install gupnp dev package

> sudo apt-get install libgupnp-1.0-dev

Now gupnp.h also located at /usr/include/gupnp-1.0/libgupnp

I try compile it using

> gcc light-server.c -L/usr/include/gupnp-1.0/

or

> gcc light-server.c -llibgupnp

And take same error.

Two questions:

1) How I can link this header?

2) If I need to install libgupnp-1.0-dev , or I can use headers from repo with samples?

Comment: You need to *include* header files, and link with libraries. Header files are not libraries, so you don't link them. It seems to me that your compiler cannot find the include files. You may try to explicitly tell it by `-I/path/to/the/header/file`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the second question, you probably do not want to install that dev package, because you are making a local equivalent.

You need to tell gcc where to find the local copies of the library and headers from the local copy of the library. I am assuming that you have already compiled (`./configure;make`), but not installed it(`make install`). you need to provide to gcc both -L and -I flags pointing to `./`

If you have installed it your -L and -I flags should point to where you installed it (probably /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include respectively)